# Want to redirect a Wordpress URL to a specific page template and pass name of post

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've got a Wordpress site set up with a custom post type and custom taxonomy and custom URLs. However when I go to:

/custom-post-type/custom-taxonomy/custom-taxonomy-sub/postname

It 404s. I've tried everything and just want to create a redirect that grabs the postname and passes it to single-custom-taxonomy.php without changing the URL.

Some sort of redirect with a regex like /custom-post-type/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) and pass the third match to single-custom-taxonomy.php as a variable so it can get the post page.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you mean `(.*)` ? You should post the RewriteRule statements that you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^knowledge-center/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)', 'index.php?pagename=post_type=questions&questions=$matches[3]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');

Comment: Well done! You should accept your own answer to stop this coming up in the unanswered section.